# ¿Por qué no sirve esta condición que me piden en un ejercicio de Java?

Tags: java

La verdad es que me dieron las bases de programación en mis estudios y ahora yo he decidido estudiarla de manera autodidacta.

Me estoy guiando por el libro de Deitel 9na edición. Ahí hay un ejercicio que piden crear una clase factura que tenga un constructor y unos métodos get y set.

Resulta que hay que hacer que cuando ingresen cantidad de objetos negativas, la variable sea 0, y que cuando se escriba una cantidad de dinero negativa, sea 0.0.

Entonces yo lo he intentado, pero no entiendo por qué no funcionan las condiciones que he puesto, y esa es mi duda si alguien me enseña que estoy haciendo mal. Este es mi código:

```
package deitelClaseFactura;

public class Factura {
    private String numPieza;
    private String desPieza;
    private int cantPieza;
    private double precioUnico;

    public Factura (String nPieza, String dPieza, int cPieza, double pUnico){
        numPieza = nPieza;
        desPieza = dPieza;
        cantPieza = cPieza;
        precioUnico = pUnico;
    }

    public void setNumeroDePieza(String nPieza){
        numPieza = nPieza;
    }

    public String getNumeroDePieza(){
        return numPieza;
    }

    public void setDescripcionDePieza(String dPieza){
        desPieza = dPieza;
    }

    public String getDescripcionDePieza(){
        return desPieza;
    }

    public void setCantidadDePiezas(int cPieza){
        if(cPieza < 0){
            cPieza = 0;
            cantPieza = cPieza;
        }

    }

    public int getCantidadDePiezas(){
        return cantPieza;
    }

    public void setPrecioDePiezas(double pUnico){
        if (pUnico < 0){
            pUnico = 0.0;
            precioUnico = pUnico;
        }

    }

    public double getPrecioDePiezas(){
        return precioUnico;
    }


    public void getMontoFactura(){
        double total = precioUnico * cantPieza;
        System.out.printf("******Factura******\n");
        System.out.printf("Descripcion de Pieza a llevar:       %s\n",getDescripcionDePieza() );
        System.out.printf("Codigo de Pieza a llevar:            %s\n",getNumeroDePieza() );
        System.out.printf("Precio unitario de Pieza a llevar:  $%s\n",getPrecioDePiezas() );
        System.out.printf("Cantidad de Piezas a llevar:         %s\n",getCantidadDePiezas() );
        System.out.println("Total :                             $"+total);
    }

}
```

Comment: bienvenido a stackoverflow, creo que ya tiene respuesta, pero como dato y bajo mi punto de vista (quizas entendi mal) el problema que comenta en de su codigo no existe en dicho codigo, me explico usted habla de que tiene que ser 0, pero en ningun momento menciona que usted quiere que el resto de valores se agregen a la variable.Se lo comento porque igual que recibio una respuesta podria no haber recibido ninguna. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Mira lo que me parece incorrecto de aquí es lo siguiente. Tu tienes este código:

```
public void setCantidadDePiezas(int cPieza){
    if(cPieza < 0){
        cPieza = 0;
        cantPieza = cPieza;
    }

}
```

Aquí estas diciendo que si la cantidad de piezas es menor a 0 la cantidad de piezas se ponga a 0. Pero, si es mayor no guardas la cantidad de piezas. Entonces una solución es ponerlo así:

```
public void setCantidadDePiezas(int cPieza){
    // Si es menor que 0, pones las piezas a 0.
    if(cPieza < 0){
        cPieza = 0;
    }
    //Guardas la nueva cantidad de piezas sea 0 o más que 0.
    cantPieza = cPieza;
}
```

Lo mismo debes hacer para los demás casos.

NOTA: Ojo al constructor:

```
public Factura (String nPieza, String dPieza, int cPieza, double pUnico){
    numPieza = nPieza;
    desPieza = dPieza;
    cantPieza = cPieza;
    precioUnico = pUnico;
}
```

Cuando instancias el objecto no estas comprobando los casos negativos! Una buena manera de corregir esto es la siguiente:

```
public Factura (String nPieza, String dPieza, int cPieza, double pUnico){

    // Llamas al setter desde el constructor, en el setter haceces todas las comprobaciones necesarias. Esto para cada atributo que requiera una comprobación. 
    this.setCantidadDePiezas(cPieza);

    desPieza = dPieza;
    cantPieza = cPieza;
    precioUnico = pUnico;
}
```

Saludos :)